# There is a 3-connected 5-regular simple $n$-vertex planar graph iff $n$ satisfies....?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, planar-graphs, graph-drawing

Is there any characterization on the set of integers $n$ such that there is a 3-connected 5-regular simple $n$-vertex planar graph?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a 3-connected 5-regular simple $n$-vertex planar graph if and only if $n=12$ or $n \ge 16$ is even.  See [Recursive generation of 5-regular graphs](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-00202-1_12) by Mahdieh Hasheminezhad, Brendan D. McKay, Tristan Reeves in *WALCOM: Algorithms and Computation*, eds. Das and Uehara, *Lecture Notes in Computer Science*, vol 5431, Springer 2009.  The number of such graphs is given in [OEIS A308489](https://oeis.org/A308489).

They use a set of 7 graphs that are irreducible under a system of expansions & reductions and, as is common for contemporary graph theory, computer assistance.  E.g., "The program completed execution in 21 seconds.  In total, 39621 induced subgraphs were found..."

Comment: Those up to 36 vertices are at http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/planegraphs.html .

Answer (score 10):

There are no such graphs when $n$ is odd, by the handshaking lemma.

Conversely, for all even $n \geq 224$, we claim such a graph exists.

In particular, given two planar 5-regular graphs $G$, $H$ each drawn on the surface of a sphere, we can define the 'connected sum' of the graphs as follows:

- remove a small disk (containing one vertex) from the sphere on which $G$ is drawn;
- remove a small disk (containing one vertex) from the sphere on which $H$ is drawn;
- combine the two resulting hemispheres at their equator.

The resulting graph (which may depend on the chosen vertices) has $|G| + |H| - 2$ vertices, and inherits the planarity, 5-regularity, and 3-connectedness of $G$ and $H$.

Now, given an even integer $n \geq 224$, we can find integers $i, j \geq 0$ such that $n = 2 + 10i + 58j$. Then we can construct an $n$-vertex graph with the desired properties by taking the connected sum of $i$ copies of the icosahedron and $j$ copies of the snub dodecahedron.

---

This leaves finitely many values of $n$ to check, namely the even numbers between 14 and 222.

Comment: great answer! Great that you present this simple construction

Comment: Fun application of the Frobenius problem going from $2+10i+58j$ to 224.  Using your construction with the icosahedron and the 16-vertex graph Brendan & collaborators found covers graphs with $n = 2+10i+14j$ vertices and brings the cases to check down to 14, 18, 20, 24, 28, 34, 38, 48.