# Is there a way to generate all 5-connected 5-regular planar graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

My question was partly inspired by the question linked below.

- [There is a 3-connected 5-regular simple $n$-vertex planar graph iff $n$ satisfies....?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366196/there-is-a-3-connected-5-regular-simple-n-vertex-planar-graph-iff-n-satisfie)

I see a wonderful construction of Adam P. Goucher, which guarantees that  **3-connected 5-regular planar graphs are infinitely numerous**. I wonder if there is a similar construct for the 5-connected 5-regular planar graphs. (Maybe I don't need to generate all of them like the title of this post.)

[image]

I noted the number of 5-connected 5-regular  planar graphs with at most 36 vertices in the following paper.

- Hasheminezhad M, McKay B, Reeves T. Recursive generation of simple planar 5-regular graphs and pentangulations[J]. 2011.

[image]

Enough such graphs to convince me there are an unlimited number of such graphs.  And when $n$ is large enough, for every $n$ there is a graph that I want.

Comment: Surely the exact same construction works? $\gcd(16-2,18-2) = 2$ and the Frobenius number of 7 and 8 is 41 so there's a graph for any even $n \ge 86$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure if the same construction can keep the new graph 5-connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

This construction is from the paper "Pairs of Hamiltonian circuits in 5-connected planar graphs" by Joseph Zaks. This is the "connected sum" of a 5-regular planar graph with an icosahedral graph.

[image: graph substitution]

Let $G$ be a 5-valent 5-connected planar graph and $v$ a vertex of it. Replace $v$ by the 11-vertex graph shown above. The new graph is 5-valent, 5-connected, planar and has 10 more vertices. Thus there is an infinitude of such graphs.